# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) of java application because of below pom file

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <!-- mvn package 报错 版本不够 #using-boot-maven-java-version -->
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

  </properties>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.sudy.zjggjccm</groupId>
  <artifactId>sudy-zjggjccm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>
  <name>zjggjccm</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
      <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.43</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mybatis生成 jar包 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-ext</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Spring Milestones</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
          <!-- <jvmArguments>-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m</jvmArguments> -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when I used above pom file to build maven project, and will not run anything on my Eclipse|IDEA|NetBean. For others IDEs it runs well. I have deleted some dependencies from this pom, then app will run . I don't know how to process this problem. but It's a bigggggggg worries.Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to mention your project's configuration classes. Just pom is not sufficient.

Comment: any code in main() doesn't run. e.g. System.out.println("x");

Comment: @Adya  See seconde comment

Answer (score 0):

What you see is typical to the foloowng scenario:

1. A thread exhausts its stack space; EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW 
   exception (0xC00000FD) is risen.
2. A thread swallows EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW and continue 
   execution.
3. At the next attempt to grow stack, the system takes control, 
   issues EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xC0000005) exception and 
   terminates the process immediately - without any GUI message!

Comment: If that is reason,how can I handle that.I grow stack space by -Xss,but not effect.

Comment: Open your run configuration for Java application then in arguments tab there will be VM arguments text box , write -Xss1m , this will increase your stack size.

Comment: Try by adding in eclipse.ini these argumnts -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Xms512m And the problem can be of memory size as well. Try to increase the Ram size that you have allocated in 32 bit machine for eclipse as -Xmx8g if you have 16 Gb ram